# Use regular expression to replace character in specific position

Tags: regex, vb.net

I want to replace the dash(-) to space from a string at position 12.
I cannot use replace("-"," ") because there may a negative number in the string.

I had try (?<=^(?:.{11})).  but it only get the result at first line.

Are there any solution?

```
 K120613763-01       1100625     TL             -11,008                 0           -11,008                                                                                        
 N123203270-02       1101024     PWL               -387                 0              -387                                                                                        
 I200543078-01       1101029     PDDW              -311                 0              -311                                                                                        
 A122285277-03       1101101     PWL                530                 0               530                                                                                      
 A127477426-03       1101101     PWL                458                 0               458
```

I want the result like below.

```
 K120613763 01       1100625     TL             -11,008                 0           -11,008                                                                                        
 N123203270 02       1101024     PWL               -387                 0              -387                                                                                        
 I200543078 01       1101029     PDDW              -311                 0              -311                                                                                        
 A122285277 03       1101101     PWL                530                 0               530                                                                                      
 A127477426 03       1101101     PWL                458                 0               458
```

Note: Lines start with a space

I use vb.net to programming in uipath.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(strTxt, "/(?<=^(?:.{11}))./gm"," ")
```

Comment: Which tool/programming language do you use?

Comment: Going forward, please [edit] your question rather than hide details in comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can match a hyphen after 11 characters and use a multiline notation like

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(strTxt, "(?m)(?<=^.{11})-"," ")
```

Comment: You do not have to use fully qualified path to `Regex` if `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions` was used before. Also, you can use `RegexOptions.Multiline` option as the third argument to `Regex.Replace` method, as an alternative to the use of the `(?m)` inline modifier.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes of course :-) good point. I left it like this as this is the OP's line in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative look behind to match the 12th character:

```
(?<=^.{11}).
```

(see [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/unCaMIWLZX2HPh))

And replace it with a `-`

You'll need to use the "global" option when doing the replace.

Comment: why I use same logic but the result only on first line in this website.
https://regex101.com/r/N5FSAD/1

Comment: @ChienWenLin you need to set global modifier to tell regex to not return after first match. So click on the `/` at the end and select global there. Also select multiline, so that regex treats `^` as a begin of each line.

Answer (score 0):

It's all flavor dependent, but usally `^` will me mean start of input, Use the `m`ultiline modier `/re/m`:

```
/(?<=^(?:.{11}))./m
```

and a replace function sometimes only replaces the first occasion of the pattern use the `g`lobal modifer as well: `/re/g`:

```
/(?<=^(?:.{11}))./gm
```

Answer (score 0):

`/(?<=^\s\S{10})-(?=.*$)/gmi`

### Explanation

- **Positive Lookbehind** `(?<=^\s\S{10})` Assert that the Regex below matches:

  - `^` asserts position at start of a line
  - `\s` matches any whitespace character (equivalent to `[\r\n\t\f\v \u00a0\u1680\u2000-\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000\ufeff]`)
  - `\S` matches any non-whitespace character (equivalent to `[^\r\n\t\f\v \u00a0\u1680\u2000-\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000\ufeff]`)
  - `{10}` matches the previous token exactly 10 time
- `-` matches the character `-` with index 45<sub>10</sub> (2D<sub>16</sub> or 55<sub>8</sub>) literally (case insensitive)
- **Positive Lookahead** `(?=.*$)` Assert that the Regex below matches:

  - `.` matches any character (except for line terminators)
  - `*` matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  - `$` asserts position at the end of a line
- **Global pattern flags**

  - `g` modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
  - `m` modifier: multi line. Causes `^` and `$` to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
  - `i` modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])

A working example can be found here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cLZeka

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(?<=^\s\S{10})-(?=.*$)";
        string substitution = @" ";
        string input = @" K120613763-01       1100625     TL             -11,008                 0           -11,008                                                                                        
 N123203270-02       1101024     PWL               -387                 0              -387                                                                                        
 I200543078-01       1101029     PDDW              -311                 0              -311                                                                                        
 A122285277-03       1101101     PWL                530                 0               530                                                                                      
 A127477426-03       1101101     PWL                458                 0               458                                                                                      ";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;
        
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
        string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
    }
}
```